# Different results in Java and Python when computing powers

Tags: java, python

I am trying to teach myself Java by working through the problems on projecteuler.net, as I have done previously with Python. When attempting problem 16, I replicated the method I used previously in Python. However the result output was different in the two languages. I think it is something to do with Java data types being different from Python. The problem is to sum the digits in the number 2^1000.

In Python:

```
def sumdigits(n):
s = 0
while n > 0:
    s = s + (n % 10)
    n = n / 10
return s
print sumdigits(pow(2,1000))
```

In Java:

```
    public static double SumDigits(double n){
            double s = 0;
            while (n > 0){
                s = s + (n % 10);
                n = n / 10;}
            return s;
            }

System.out.println(SumDigits(Math.pow(2,1000)));
```

Python produced the correct result and Java produced 1197.1463275484991

Why would these be different?

Comment: Because you are using a `double`? Try using an integral type.

Comment: But Math.pow(2,1000) is outside the range of the int type.

Comment: You'll have to use `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, [`double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) cannot accurately represent 2^1000. As a floating-point number, `Math.pow(2,1000)` is `1.0715086071862673E301`.

To get the result that you want, use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) which preserves the actual value of 2^1000.

```
public static BigInteger sumDigits(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger num = n;
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger ten = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    while (num.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
        sum = sum.add(num.mod(ten));
        num = num.divide(ten);
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sumDigits(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(1000)));
}
```

The output of the above code is `1366`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic number types in Java are int and double. Both cannot handle a number with 1000 bits. Python has a arbitrary large integer type builtin. For Java you have to find another solution.

In languages with arbitrary large integer arithmetics this problem is trivial

```
print sum(int(x) for x in str(2**1000))
```

If you don't have this tool, you have to code multiplication by two on your own.